Is there any problem using ISO string in Firestore instead of their Timestamp object?
The recommended type to represent timestamps in Firestore is Firestore Timestamp, but this is not the same as the Date object in JS.
The problem with this is that I need to convert/stringify these objects when we get them from the DB, and maintain 2 TypeScripts interfaces if we want to be strict.
These are not big problems, but I was thinking on saving timestamps using ISO strings (e.g.: '2024-04-16T20:37:22.711Z'), and having into account that these strings are safe to compare, I can safely do queries like:
const firstDayOfThisYear = '2024-01-01'
// createdAt contains an ISO string
const q = query(collectionRef, where("createdAt", ">", firstDayOfThisYear));

Is there any problem with this? Is this query using strings less performant than using Firestore Timestamp?


Is there any problem with this?

No, not until you need something from these strings that you didn't design for.

Is this query using strings less performant than using Firestore Timestamp?

No.  But consider benchmarking this yourself anyway.  It's a good practice if you're really concerned about performance.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78338682/6841228

could you elaborate on what would be those limitations?

I did some simple benchmarking to check the performance and surprisingly the query using ISO string is at minimum 2 times faster than using Timestamp.
Here is the script I used for the benchmark with some results at the end: https://gist.github.com/cundejo/4a22f3245c566eec378b36252f764010
My usage of these timestamps ISO strings is very limited, I will use them only in queries with < or >. For another type of work it's better to use Firestore Timestamp.

So in the example you have a query where you compare two timestamps. I would imagine using ISO strings for timestamps in Firestore queries can be less performant compared to using Firestore Timestamp objects just because of Storage Efficiency - Firestore Timestamps are stored as integers representing seconds and nanoseconds since the Unix epoch. This is a compact format compared to ISO strings, which are text representations. These text representations would need to be parsed.
And then there is Native Indexing - I think Firestore can efficiently index Firestore Timestamp objects directly. When you query using Timestamps, Firestore can leverage these indexes to quickly find relevant documents. With ISO strings, Firestore might need to convert them internally before comparison, adding an extra processing step.
So yes, I think using ISO strings would be less performant given there will be an extra step involved with parsing and the inability to leverage Firestore's storage indexing.
I don't see any other reason why you can't do what you're suggesting. Seems innocuous enough and is definitely not incorrect.
